# Empirical cumulative distribution function exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(Y_n)$~discrete uniform on the set $Y_n(\Omega)=\{0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \ldots, \frac{n-1}{n}, 1\}$.

Can you give the cumulative distribution function?

I know that $\displaystyle F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{x_i \leq x \}}$

Answer (score 1):

The sum in the CDF simply counts the number of integers $j=0,\ldots,n$ for which $\frac{j}{n}\le x$.
If this inequality holds for some $j$, then also $j\le nx$, and the number of integers satisfying this is simply $\lfloor nx\rfloor+1$ (we add $1$ since we always have $0\le x$).
Note that the total number of possibilities here is not actually $n$, but $n+1$ since again, $\mathsf{Y}_n$ can take the value $0$.
Thus, the CDF is $F_n(x)=\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{n+1}$